# resize children elements according to the length

Tags: html, css

I have the following html structure

```
<div class="wrapper"> 

<ul class="list"></ul>

</div>
```

which the ul element is dynamically filled by li elements, but when they are several (more than 5) exceed the height of the wrapper element, so I would like to know if there is a way to adjust these elements to its container or viceversa.

Comment: You probably need to find the CSS of wrapper and paste it above as well.

Comment: Do you odd that it is getting cut off... do you have a fiddle we can look at, or some css code?

Answer (score 0):

So you have two cases here:

**Case A**

Adjust the objects to the `width` of the container you can use:

```
li {
    display:table-cell;
    width:1%;
}
```

You can check the **[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/1rq5e617/)**

**Case B**

Adjus the container to the size of the elements you can use:

```
ul {
    white-space:nowrap;
    display:inline-block;
}

li {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

You can check the **[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/1rq5e617/1/)**

---

Also this options can have other variations all depens on your needs an contents.

Comment: The problem I'm delaing is whith the height of the container? because for example of 5 li, 3 are within the container and 2 out of it.